# Converting area of a polygon from steradians to square kilometers using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, area, d3

How can I find the area of a polygon in square km using D3.js? I'm not even really sure whether to use [d3.geo.path.area](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_area) or [d3.geo.area](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#area).

Here is my code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aohx8vme/1/)):

```
var d = {
    "type":"Feature",
    "id":"7525",
    "properties":{"name":"Paris, 11e arrondissement","id":"117525"},
    "geometry": {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[2.377,48.8719],[2.3991,48.8481],[2.369,48.8532],
                       [2.3684,48.8557],[2.3639,48.8674],[2.377,48.8719]]]
    }
  };
var w=720, h=640;
var projection = d3.geo.orthographic().scale(3660).rotate([-3,-46.35])
                    .clipExtent([[0,0], [w,h]]).translate([w/2,h/2]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

console.log('path area', path.area(d));
console.log('geo area', d3.geo.area(d));
```

For `path area` I get `1.0841410092907608` and for `geo area` I get `8.101249039703731e-8`.

The docs suggest that the first is the result in pixels, and the second is the result in steradians. Is it possible to convert steradians to square km?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [maths is fun page](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/steradian.html), or the [wikipedia steridian article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian), you will discover that there are 12.56637 steradians in a sphere. So, if you take the area of the earth to be, 510,072,000 sq km, then, given your area of 8.101249039703731e-8, and plugging in these numbers, you get:

```
8.101249039703731e-8 / 12.56637 * 510,072,000 = 3.288 km².
```

or in your original formulation (using d3.geo.area, to answer your question),

```
var sq_km = d3.geo.area(d) / 12.56637 * 510072000;
```

As, as sanity check, converting to the geography data type in Postgis and taking the area:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((2.377 48.8719, 2.3991 48.8481,
    2.369 48.8532, 2.3684 48.8557, 2.3639 48.8674, 2.377 48.8719,
    2.377 48.8719))')::geography)/1000000;
```

returns: `3.298 km²`

not identical, but close, and probably more useful than steradians here on planet earth. The difference, no doubt, is down to the assumption of a sphere in the first calculation. If this is close enough for your needs, then it would be trivially easy to write the above formula in D3.js. If you need the spheroid, there are Javascript libs available, for example, [geographiclib.js](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geographiclib.js), that you could plug in, with a little more work.

According to wikipedia, the [area of the 11th arrondisement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11th_arrondissement_of_Paris) is 3.67 km², which is clearly in the same ballpark. Judging by the boundary shown on the map on the same wikipedia page, it is slightly more complex than the 6 vertices of your polygon above, which could account for the differences observed?

Comment: You are welcome. It did make me wonder why d3 uses steradians, but it was fun figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian):

> For a general sphere of radius r, any portion of its surface with area A = r<sup>2</sup> subtends one steradian.

So you can multiply your steradians value by r<sup>2</sup> to get the area value.  Using `r = 6371 km`:

```
8.101249039703731e-8 * (6371 * 6371) = 3.288 km²
```